# python string prefixed with _, what is it?

Tags: python

I see _ in some code before strings, e.g.

`lable = _("Password")`

What does it mean? One told me it is for multilanguage support. I have not found anything on the internet to confirm this...

Many thanks for your help.

.
--update--
Thanks, @thg435 , after seeing your text, I've found exactly what is:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
```

'-' is a shorthand...

Comment: @PuffinGDI: Not that meaning.

Comment: @PuffinGDI It's a bit different in this case.

Comment: Thanks all. I learn more. It's my misunderstand.

Answer (score 6):

The name `_` is often defined as an alias to `gettext.gettext`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html for details.
Yes, it's for internationalization.

However, since `_` is a valid identifier (and hence a function name), it can be used for other purposes. It's completely up to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier), a valid Python identifier can be like this

```
identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
```

It can be any valid expression, starting with a `letter` or `_` and then it can have letters, digits or `_`. So, `_` is a valid variable name in Python. Your code looks like a function call, where the name of the function is `_`. For example,

```
def _(arg):
    print arg

_("Password")
```

would print

```
Password
```